# Docker compose volume bind source path working for Windows and Linux

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using Windows 10 to developing/hosting containers, but afterall containers finally will be deployed to Linux host.
I'd like to have docker-compose volumes valid for both Windows and Linux host enviroments

```
#localy win10 for dev testing
 volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: C:/xyz/db
        target: /home/db
 
#linux production
 volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /home/dockers/db
        target: /home/db
```

The only reasonable untested option I found is to put volume inside working directory (relative path)

```
      - type: bind
        source: ./DirectoryIWantToMountInDockerContainer #both systems local folder
        target: /path/where/mount/source
```

Comment: If the forward slashes in the first example work on Windows, can you use a relative path `./db`?

Comment: Yes and It should work fine, but I wonder If its possible to get 2 different absolute paths depending on container system

Comment: Use environment variables to pass the path.